# DataStudio system error in Chromium when change date filter

Tags: looker-studio

I just realized that I got Datastudio system error when I try to change Date range filter in my global chart on my webpage via iframe link : https://webcovid19.live/index.html#global
When I try the same action on direct report: https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/7ff6cf1b-7478-4cb1-88b2-83246fc83234/page/WadOB
, here is no issues.
Affected browser is Chromium.Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit).
On Firexox / Chrome : no issues found
[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just realized that it was not good idea ruuning at same time Ghostery Adbloker and googletagmanager. :)
Issue solved.